# How do I make the text and the Image align next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have two div one has text - div.home and the other has image - div.main-home-img. These two div are not aligning next to each other. How do I make them align next to each other in HTML and CSS?

This is how it currently looks like:

[image]

```css
.small-text-1,
.small-text-2 {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.main-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15vh;
  margin-left: 8vw;
}

.para-text-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 8vw;
  margin-top: 3.5vh;
}

.para-text-1 p span {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.para-text-1 p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 3.5vh;
}

.btn-home-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 8vw;
  margin-top: 5vh;
}

.btn-home-text button {
  width: 7vw;
  height: 5.5vh;
  color: #ffff;
  background-color: #ff3c00;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.blank-text {
  display: inline-block;
}

.Blank-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2vw;
}

.Blank-text p {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.arrow-home-img img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline;
}

.arrow-home-img {
  margin-top: 1vh;
  margin-left: 0vw;
  display: inline-block;
}

.Works-text-home-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 4.5vh;
  margin-left: 8vw;
}

.Works-text-home-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 3vh;
  margin-left: 8vw;
}

.Works-text-home-2 h2,
p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.Works-text-home-3 {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5vw;
}

.Works-text-home-3 h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-home-img img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20vw;
}

.main-home-img {
  margin-left: 79.8vw;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="Home">
  <div class="main-text">
    <span class="small-text-1">Hi! I Am</span>
    <br>
    <span class="small-text-2">Ashman Singh</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="para-text-1">
    <p>Designing user interfaces for over <span>7 years</span> <br> as a developer</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="btn-home-text">
    <button>Hire Me</button>
  </div>

  <div class="Blank-text">
    <p>
      Projects
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="arrow-home-img">
    <img src="/Images/up-arrow.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <!-- <div class="img-text-logo-home">
            <img src="/Images/code.png" alt="">
        </div> -->
  <br>
  <div class="Works-text-home-1">
    <h2>84+</h2>
    <p>Clients on work <br> worldwide</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="Works-text-home-2">
    <h2>572</h2>
    <br>
    <p>Projects done</p>
  </div>

  <div class="Works-text-home-3">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
    <br>
    <p>shivanisomghignou@gmail.com</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="main-home-img">
  <img src="/Images/ludovic-migneault-4uj3iZ5m084-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have two columns you can make use of the [CSS Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) or [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) System.

```css
.small-text-1, .small-text-2 {
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.main-text {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 15vh;
    margin-left: 8vw;
}

.para-text-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 8vw;
    margin-top: 3.5vh;
}

.para-text-1 p span {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.para-text-1 p {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 3.5vh;
}

.btn-home-text {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 8vw;
    margin-top: 5vh;
}

.btn-home-text button  {
    width: 7vw;
    height: 5.5vh;
    color: #ffff;
    background-color: #ff3c00;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.blank-text {
    display: inline-block;
}

.Blank-text {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2vw;
}

.Blank-text p {
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.arrow-home-img img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline;
}

.arrow-home-img {
    margin-top: 1vh;
    margin-left: 0vw;
    display: inline-block;
}

.Works-text-home-1  {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 4.5vh;
    margin-left: 8vw;
}

.Works-text-home-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    margin-left: 8vw;
}

.Works-text-home-2 h2,p {
    display: inline-block;
}


.Works-text-home-3  {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5vw;
}

.Works-text-home-3 h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-home-img img{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 20vw;
}

.main-home-img {
    /*margin-left: 79.8vw;
    display: inline-block;*/
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div class="Home">

    <div class="main-text">
      <span class="small-text-1">
        Hi! I Am
      </span>
      <br>
      <span class="small-text-2">
        Ashman Singh
      </span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="para-text-1">
      <p>Designing user interfaces for over <span>7 years</span> <br> as a developer</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="btn-home-text">
      <button>Hire Me</button>
    </div>

    <div class="Blank-text">
      <p>
        Projects
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="arrow-home-img">
      <img src="/Images/up-arrow.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="img-text-logo-home">
            <img src="/Images/code.png" alt="">
        </div> -->
    <br>
    <div class="Works-text-home-1">
      <h2>84+</h2>
      <p>Clients on work <br> worldwide</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="Works-text-home-2">
      <h2>572</h2>
      <br>
      <p>Projects done</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Works-text-home-3">
      <h2>Contact</h2>
      <br>
      <p>shivanisomghignou@gmail.com</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="main-home-img">
    <img src="/Images/ludovic-migneault-4uj3iZ5m084-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

All I needed to do is wrap your code with another `div` and make it a flexbox.

```
<div style="display: flex">
   <div class="Home">
      ... Your old code ...
   </div>
   <div class="main-home-img">
      <img src="/Images/ludovic-migneault-4uj3iZ5m084-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

You can also remove the CSS properties for your `.main-home-img` class:

```
.main-home-img {
    /*margin-left: 79.8vw;
    display: inline-block;*/
}
```

Please read the links I posted for Flexbox and Grid to get a good understanding on how to use it properly, make it responsive, etc.